# what if key is undefined in map in react?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

A key is required in react map to differentiate the items mapped. So what if key passed is undefined , either it will create unique key for each item or it will assign same undefined  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is no valid key supplied to an item. React will throw an error that a valid key is required. The docs says the following about keys:

*"Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:"* - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

When I have no keys available I use [uniqid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid). This package creates unique ID's that are perfect as key value. See my example below:

```js
import uniqid from 'uniqid';

const fruits = ['banana','apple', 'cherry', 'banana']

fruits.map(fruit => <span key={uniqid()}>{fruit}</span>)
```

Comment: using key in that way with `uniqid` kinda defeats the purpose: React will think it is a new element and discard the whole DOM representing that item in the list and create a new one. If the list is e.g. append-only, it is fairly safe to use the index. For a simple string like that, key can be the string itself.

Comment: Well, my questin was not about providing unique keys to react list but my question is about what will be the behavior of the app if key passed to list is undefined in all items?

Comment: Agreed with @flq, using `uniqid` is not the way to go. If the list doesn't change (or just gets appended to), use index. If it does change, restructure your data so that it's a list of objects where the object contains some unique key that's bound with the data in some way. Or, if the data is unique (so not in this example because of duplicate bananas), you can use the item as the key.

Answer (score 1):

If you passed `undefined`, it will assign same `undefined` for all. And throws an warning

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `undefined`. Keys
> should be unique so that components maintain their identity across
> updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or
> omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future
> version.

The easiest way of solving the key problem is to use `React.Children.toArray` method. You can wrap your map in `React.Children.toArray` and React will do it's thing and pick keys for you! Here is a simple example:

```
const App = () => {
  const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  return (
    <>
      {React.Children.toArray(arr.map(item => <h3>{item}</h3>))}
    </>
  );
};
```

You can also use `index` from `map` as a key, but it's not recommended.

```
const App = () => {
  const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  return (
    <>
      {arr.map((item, index) => <h3 key={`${index}`}>{item}</h3>)}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It really depends how your list will mutate - if you e.g. only append items, an index would be perfectly fine. I wouldn't know in what ways the substring approach would help, tbh.

Comment: @flq yeah, you are right. It depends how we mutate the list. Agree with you, substring won't help here. Updating my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The key attribute is for identification, if you pass no keys or key with undefined value, React will give warning as "**Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop**".

But Remember, anytime you want to insert any new element in the middle of the list, the order of the list will not be same and **you may see unexpected output/ unnecessary rerendering of items which are having same value as previous render**. That is why, React always recommends to add unique keys.

To see undefined key behaviour: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-leakey-crj2dm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: well, my question is about the unexpected behavior of the list in case of an undefined key, e.g if I pass the same key for two items of the list and I add a dropdown menu to each item then if I click the item with the same key both items will expand because key provided was same, but if I pass undefined key to all items they do not expand at the same time, why is that? can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

To handle this issue you can use a third party library which generate a uinque Id to use for each item:

1.You can use [uniqueId from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqueId) 
2.You can use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)
By using one of them you can add a unique Id to every item in the iterable object and after that you can use that uinque Id as a key:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import _ from 'lodash';

....

const iterableObject: Array<{ [x: string]: any }> = [{}];

//by using lodash
iterableObject.map((item) => item.uId = _.uniqueId('cartItem_'));
//or by using uuid
iterableObject.map((item) => item.uId = uuid());

...

iterableObject.map((item) => (<div key={item.uId}> ... </div>));
```